# QML connect signal to function

Tags: qt, qml

I was getting my self familiar with QML in QT5. So i was trying to make the code from the follwing video: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkzncJ71mm0)

In this video the code:`send.connect(target.receive());` is used. But This part does not work. I am getting the error:

> qrc:/Receiver.qml:8: Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString

Is this method deprecated or am i doing something wrong?

**main.qml**

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Jurassic World")

Background {
    id: background
    anchors.fill: parent
    target: sender

    Sender {
        id: sender
        y: 145
        displayText: "Sender"
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 50
        target: receiver
    }

    Receiver {
        id: receiver
        x: 376
        y: 158
        displayText: "Receiver"
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 50
        width: sender.width
    }
}
}
```

**Receiver.qml**

```
Cirkel {
id: receiveButton

function receive(value)
{
    displayText = value
    clicknotify.running = true
}

SequentialAnimation on buttonColor
{
    id: clicknotify
    running: false

    ColorAnimation {
        from: "#afc4cb"
        to: "red"
        duration: 200
    }

    ColorAnimation {
        from: "red"
        to: "#afc4cb"
        duration: 200
    }
}
}
```

**Sender.qml**

```
Cirkel {
id: sendButton

property int counter: 0
property Receiver target: null

signal send(string value)

onTargetChanged: {
    send.connect(target.receive());
}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onClicked: {
        counter++
        parent.send(counter)
        displayText = counter
    }

    onPressed: parent.buttonColor = "green"
    onReleased: parent.buttonColor = "#afc4cb"
}
}
```

**Question:**
How can i link a signal from one qml to a other qml function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

```
send.connect(target.receive());
```

where you call `target.receive()` and try to connect its return value to `send`.

What you want is:

```
send.connect(target.receive);
```

where you connect `send` to the function `receive` itself.

---

Recommendation:

> Also try the declarative way, using a `Connection`-object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, in Sender.qml just do:

```
signal send(int value)
...
sendButton.send(counter)
```

and in main.qml just do

```
Sender {
    id: sender
    ...
    onSend: receiver.receive(value)
}
```

That's all. No need for the whole target assignment.
And by the way, you have a data type issue in the receive function (integer to string)
Fix with this:

```
function receive(value)
{
    displayText = "" + value
    clicknotify.running = true
}
```

In general, a signal in QML can be handled as a function by adding "on" and uppercase first letter.

For example, a Button exposes the `clicked` signal, and when you handle it you use `onClicked`

Comment: i changed this: displayText = "" + value.

Comment: now i get the error: qrc:/Sender.qml:12: Error: Function.prototype.connect: target is not a function